# How to use interactive shell in nodeJS / express

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, kubernetes, backup

I want to make a NodeJS server who will made backup of a db postgre who is on my K8s cluster
I have donne the following code but im unable to make it work i got the following error :

`Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file`

```
function executeCommand(command) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = shell.exec(command);
        if (result.code === 0) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            console.error(`Erreur lors de l'exécution de la commande : ${result.stderr}`);
            reject(`Erreur lors de l'exécution de la commande : ${command}`);
        }
    });
}


async function backup() {
    try {
        console.log('Backup en cours...');
        await executeCommand('kubectl exec -it mypod -- /bin/sh');
        console.log('1');
        await executeCommand('pg_dump -U myuser -d testdb -f /tmp/backup.sql');
        console.log('2');
        await executeCommand('exit');
        console.log('3');
        await executeCommand('kubectl cp mypod:/tmp/backup.sql ./backup.sql');
        console.log('Backup effectué avec succès !');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Erreur lors de la sauvegarde : ', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of why you don't get a shell, but even if you did -> `await executeCommand('exit');`  doesn't make sense, here you would be creating a shell to then instantly exit???   each `shell.exec` is a brand new shell.

Comment: Do you actually need the interactive shell, or can you `kubectl exec ... -- pg_dump ...`?  Better still, can you start a background `kubectl port-forward mypod 5432`, and run `pg_dump` locally (and then you won't need `kubectl cp` at the end)?